# How to replace a placeholder with link in email Template

Tags: symfony, twig

Hi I have define and Place holder in between an email template in admin as:

```
Dear {{ CUSTOMER_NAME }},

Please click {{ LINK_CONSTANT }} to see your order details.
```

So in controller while creating this email template I want to create dynamic link for the `{{ LINK_CONSTANT }}`. I am trying following:

```
$portalUrl = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $request->getHttpHost() . $request->getBasePath(). '/app_dev.php/XDEF344545';

$urlLink = "<a href = ".$portalUrl.">Click Here</a>";

$template = $this->get('twig')->createTemplate($contents);

$templateString = $template->render(array(
    'CUSTOMER_NAME' => 'Sam',
    'LINK_CONSTANT'=>$urlLink,
));

return $this->render('action_and_message/messageTemplates/emailTemplates/emailTemplate.html.twig', array(
    'data' =>$templateString
));
```

But it print the link, as it is while rending template:
http://192.168.10.23/project/route/XCBNH343. I want instead a hyper link

```
as : <a href= "http://192.168.10.23/project/route/XCBNH343">Click Here</a>
```

What is need to done to achieve this?

Thanks advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the template file(xxx.twig) which you pass at the end of the controller, you could use the raw filter.

That is

```
{{ LINK_CONSTANT | raw }}
```

instead of

```
{{ LINK_CONSTANT }}.
```

Comment: The requirement is to keep constant only in template not a link .

{{LINK_CONSTANT}} only this. is it possible?

Comment: Oh sorry, you already had it in the $urlLink variable. So would you like to escape that a tag html chunk, not rendered as a link?

Comment: In that case, you can use raw filter. {{ LINK_CONSTANT | raw }}

Comment: you mean like this:

$templateString =   $template->render(
                           array('CUSTOMER_NAME' => 'Sam',
                               'LINK_CONSTANT| raw'=>$urlLink,

                           )
                       );
?

Comment: Because I am rendering  view Like:

return $this->render('action_and_message/messageTemplates/emailTemplates/emailTemplate.html.twig', array(
            'data' =>$templateString
        ));
//in twig

{{data | raw}}

Comment: The filter is meant to be used in twig. So, you could use {{ LINK_CONSTANT | raw }} in the place you originally used {{ LINK_CONSTANT }}. I edited my original comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130083/discussion-between-sunil-rawat-and-scalatron-motoroller).